# PhoneGap Display Accelerometer Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, cordova

I'm using phonegap to get an accelerometer's value and print it, but I'm not sure how to display it in the main body. I'm also using JQuery. This code is taken from the accelerometer example on the Cordova (PhoneGap) website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Acceleration Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    //
    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
        alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
              document.writeln(
              'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
    //
    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>getCurrentAcceleration</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in HTML tag, use this code.

```
<p id="ax"></p>
<p id="ay"></p>
<p id="az"></p>
```

and on function onSuccess(acceleration) in javascript code. you should use this command

```
document.getElementById("ax").innerHTML = acceleration.x;
document.getElementById("ay").innerHTML = acceleration.y;
document.getElementById("az").innerHTML = acceleration.z;
```

or using jQuery like this

```
$("ax").html(acceleration.x);
$("ay").html(acceleration.y);
$("az").html(acceleration.z);
```

Comment: ok I added that but on my Android device it isn't displaying anything in those fields

Comment: Which problem now you got??